# Obtaining value in IEnumerable

Tags: vb.net, function, iterator, ienumerable

A Sobol sequence, a series of low-discrepancy random numbers in range [0,1], can be generated by first initializing a vector of direction numbers:

```
Dim V(31) As ULong
For i = 1 To 31
  V(i-1) = 2 ^ (32 - i)
Next
```

and then enumerating the elements generated by a Sobol() function (provided below) as:

```
For Each lnumber As ULong In Sobol(V)
   MessageBox.Show(lnumber / 2 ^ 32)
Next
```

This can be done as long as there are less than 2^32 values generated, the typical period of a linear congruential generator.

The question is, how can individual Sobol numbers be pulled from Sobol() without using a loop, and instead obtaining one number at a time from a single call-out to the function?  The idea would be to instantiate a public class, anywhere in my code, like

```
Dim ran As New SobolNumber()
```

and then calling for the next number using for example:

```
Dim x as Double
x = ran.NextSobolNumber
```

The Sobol() function and required Ruler() function are listed below:

```
Public Iterator Function Sobol(ByVal v() As ULong) As IEnumerable(Of ULong)
    Dim s As ULong = 0
    For Each r In Ruler()
        Yield s = s Xor v(r)
    Next r
End Function

Public Iterator Function Ruler() As IEnumerable(Of Integer)
    Yield 0
    For Each r In Ruler()
        Yield r + 1
        Yield 0
    Next r
End Function
```

Comment: This is covered in the [Iterator Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/iterators#:~:text=An%20iterator%20can%20be%20used,location%20in%20code%20is%20remembered.)

Comment: You would call `Sobol` the same way you would call any other function that takes an array argument.  You can then obtain each value by iterating on the result (using `For Each`), or you can use other Linq functions to operate on the sequence.